# How to share my deskop / screen to XMBC?

Tags: screen, xbmc, sharing, raspberrypi

What is the easiest/best way to share my screen (and preferably sound) from my Ubuntu laptop to my RPi (running OpenElec / XBMC)

My goal is to be able to play games on my ubuntu laptop without needing to hook it up to my TV set and amplifier each time. The raspberry is already connected to them and I can use AirPlay from my Ipad without trouble, so it would seem possible to do something similar from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Google search on VNC and go from there.

In short: you need a vnc-server running on your Ubuntu laptop and a vnc-client on the Pi